# Change Ember Route from View

Tags: ember.js

I have a view object that looks more or less like this (which I use for modals as the name suggests)

```
App.ModalView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
            var self = this,
                popupName = this.popupName || '';

            if (popupName) {
                $('.' + popupName).fadeIn('slow');

                $('.overlay').click(function () {
                    self.close();
                });
            }
        });
    },

    close: function () {
        var popupName = this.popupName || '';

        $('.' + popupName).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.' + popupName).remove();
        });

        window.location = '/#/';
    }
});
```

So when the user clicks on the overlay, I want to close my popup and change the route to the index. I can do that naively with window.location, but I guess that's not how it is intented to be. What's the Ember way to do this?

Comment: You can access your controller from that view, and use 'transitionToRoute' using your controller. Check this url for more information http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ControllerMixin.html#method_transitionToRoute

Comment: Ok, great point, solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it (thanks to fanta's comment) with the following line:

```
this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('index');
```